# Simpiflying Exponential Expressions

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

> Note that  $x = 5$
>
> $$\frac {x^{x+3}+ x^{x+2}}{x^{x+1}+x^{x+2}} = ?$$

This is what I'm struggling with. There's my attempt as seen below.

$$\frac {x^x.x^3+x^x.x^2}{x^x . x + x^x .x^2}$$

Factoring $x^x$ and we get

$$\frac {x^x (x^3 + x^2)}{x^x(x . x^2)} = \frac {x^3}{x} = x^2 = (5)^2 = 25$$

According to my textbook, I've found wrong answer. Correct answer seems $5$, why?

Comment: Factoring $x^x$ you get $\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{x+x^2}$.  You seem to be confusing addition with multiplication.

Comment: In the event that the multiplication (?) was a typo, then your next simplification was in error as well: $\frac{x^3+x^2}{x+x^2}\neq \frac{x^3}{x}$.  Even with it as multiplication, this simplification is unjustified.  Instead, note that $x^3+x^2=x(x+x^2)$

Answer (score 0):

write $$\frac{x^{x+2}(1+x^{x+3-x-2})}{x^{x+1}(1+x^{x+2-x-1})}$$
can you finish?

Comment: How did you get this? $\frac{x^{x+2}(1+x^{x+3-x-2})}{x^{x+1}(1+x^{x+2-x-1})}$

Comment: i have it factor out, check it and muliply out the paranthesis

Comment: the numerator is given by $$x^{x+2}+x^{x+3-x-2+x+2}$$